# Axis Customization in SSRS Stacked bar Chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I Create SSRS stacked bar chart using BIDS.Its look like,
[image]

Here,the group will shown in Vertical Axis and the Phase shown in Horizontal Axis.I need to Customize the horizontal Axis.

My question is,I dont want to show number like **10,20,30,40** instead of that I need Text for replace Number.

How to customize the Axis points?**Existing:10,20,30,40,50** but I need to change like ,**Expectation:Ten,twenty,thirty,Fourty**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bar chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked) with categories on the xAxis.